# Java Threading Error IllegalThreadState thread already started

Tags: java, android

Whenever I start my thread I always do this check.  I did not find anywhere that I called start on thread without doing the check below

```
if (!myThread.isAlive())
    myThread.start();
```

Nevertheless, I end up with IllegalThreadStateException : Thread already started.  This actually crashes my app (android).  So is there some other check I need to do before starting up a thread?

Comment: Thread may not be alive and still already started: i.e. it may have been started in the past and has already finished. Maybe that is the case here?

Comment: If two threads share a reference to myThread then they both might examine myThread.isAlive() and both see false, then they both try to start. You probably shouldn't start threads like this (passing around a Thread object that you later start). You should probably be using an ExecutorService from java.util.concurrent.Executors. If you post more details about what the Threads are doing then I can give more specific advice.

Answer (score 11):

You should check if the thread has already started using [getState()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getState%28%29) and start it only if its [state is NEW](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html), otherwise create new thread (if needed).

Comment: let me clarify this approach.  if (thread.getState() == Thead.State.NEW)

Comment: That seems to be what you are indicating however, any other criteria needed to start?  Just start whenever state is NEW?

Comment: @Androider - Sorry for late response - yes, that was my approach. start when state is not new will cause exception.

Comment: I am creating a thread just like Thread thread = new Thread(){} then how can i make the instance of the thread again...

Comment: If you do create a new thread, don't forget to start it! (like i did.)

Answer (score 3):

Do you create a new instance for myThread reference using new?
You can only perform myThread.start() once on a single instance.

Checking if it is alive is not the right way. Create a new instance.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar case here, that's why I give a late answer.

The problem is, your solution with `Thread.isAlive()` and `Thread.start()` is not multithread-safe. It can happen a first thread calls your code, executes `isAlive()` and somewhere inside `Thread.start()`, after the new thread was started and before it state is changed, a task switch occurs and a second caller executes `isAlive()` when it is still `false` thus making `start()`being called twice. To make it worse somewhere inside `start()`it seems a task switch is forced and thus this problem appears quite often.

Solution: Override `start()` to make it multithread-safe, for example

```
private final AtomicBoolean started = new AtomicBoolean(false);
/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see java.lang.Thread#start()
 */
@Override
public synchronized void start() {
    if (!started.getAndSet(true)) {
        super.start();
    }
}
```

Then your problem won't appear any more, even if `start()` accidentally is called twice.