# Implementing timeouts in software

Tags: java, android, timeout

My question might be a common requirement. Unfortunately haven't found a proper guide on it anywhere.

I require to set a timeout in software in Java. In my setup I have a mouse attached to an Android device.

Basically my Android application has two modes: ENGAGED and DISENGAGED.
By default, the application resides in DISENGAGED mode.
The app shows different screens in ENGAGED and DISENGAGED mode, which gets automatically controlled based upon the mode.
Now to enter ENGAGED mode, the user is expected to perform a left click of the mouse. The app remains in engaged mode as long as the user uses the mouse. If the user doesn't use the mouse for a period of 30 seconds, the APP goes back to DISENGAGED mode.

While in software I receive events for every touch that the user performs, obviously I don't get any event when the 30 seconds have passed since the last touch. Thus I need a proper solution for going back to disengaged mode.

How does one implement this in software? A basic outline of the code flow should suffice, need not be an exact working code. I am comfortable using semaphores, tasks, mutexs, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is start up a simple thread that waits 30 seconds and resets whenever mouse movement is detected.

It is generally recommended to implement Runnable instead of extending Thread since Java only has single inheritance.  Here's a runnable private class that should work:

```
private static class CustomRunnable implements Runnable{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        boolean waiting = true;

        while(waiting){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(30000);
                waiting = false;
                // went 30 seconds with no interrupt - go to sleep mode
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                waiting = true;
                // we were interrupted by mouse movement - restart loop
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can start the thread using

```
Thread sleepThread = new Thread(new CustomRunnable());
sleepThread.start();
```

And you can reset the thread using

```
sleepThread.interrupt();
```

Comment: Thanks. Btw, in case of no interrupt and the task going to sleep, can I call `sleepThread.start()` directly for reinitialising the timer, or do I need to do `Thread sleepThread = new Thread(new CustomRunnable())` part again?

Comment: I am stuck at one point. If the thread exits after a proper timeout, I am unable to reuse it by issuing `sleepThread.start()`. That issues an "thread already active" error. Do you know the solution for this?

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  Ignore my last comment, you just need to create a new thread if the current thread has already executed.  See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5628297/java-threading-error-illegalthreadstate-thread-already-started) post.

Answer (score 0):

Won't this do the trick:
System.currentTimeInMillis()
[API for currentTimeMillis()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29)

Comment: Thanks, but this doens't help. Nanotime only gives me the current system time. I am looking for a way to trigger the switch from ENGAGED to DISENGAGED upon a timeout.

Comment: I guess I'm confused on how complex your code is, so I'm probably out of my league on this. if you would like, post an example and I can try to help more... Good luck